# construction pie of pie charts

Tags: charts, highcharts

I have to construct pie of pie chart, for which have gone through various ways possible. I found Highcharts for data visualization. Here is a feature "drilldown" but I want the two pie charts together connecting through the arcs. To achieve the same have tried Highcharts by construction two pie charts using two  tags and using css to connect the arcs but its not achievable. please do help me to create pie of pie charts through any way possible.I have searched D3js, google charts and highcharts but couldn't implement. My code is as follows:

$(function () {
        $('#left').highcharts({

```
        title: {
            text: 'Pie of Pie charts'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                innerSize:150,
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                            ['Firefox', 45.0],
                            ['IE', 26.8],
                            ['Safari', 8.5],
                            ['Opera', 6.2],
                            ['Others', 0.7]
            ]
        }]

    });
    $('#right').highcharts({

        title: {
            text: 'Pie of Pie charts'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                innerSize:150,
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                            ['Firefox', 35],
                            ['IE', 26.8],
                            ['Safari', 8.5],
                            ['Opera', 20],
                            ['Others', 80]
            ]
        }]


    });
});
```

Comment: I don't understand how this would look. What does "connecting through the arcs" mean?

Comment: Please attach a mockup of your needed chart